# Current system time +1 minute in java

Tags: java, string, parsing

I am using below condition to get current system time as a start time and tomorrow time as stop time in my tracing logs project. But now I want starttime should be +1mins to the current system time. Can anybody help with this?

```
SimpleDateFormat date_format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
String startTime=date_format.format(new Date());
String tomorrowTime=date_format.format(new Date(new Date().getTime()+(1000*60*60*24)));
```

Thanks

Comment: How many milliseconds are there in one minute?

Comment: @vanza OP doesn't even have to know that: `TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1)`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, due to the code the OP posted, I think he has to know! If he knows `tomorrow` in `today + 1000*60*60*24`, how can he not know what is `now + one minute`?

Answer (score 7):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);

Date currentTimePlusOneMinute = cal.getTime();
```

Comment: Actually, involving the Calendar for this straightforward job is a bit of an overkill. Minutes are a homogeneous unit, unlike months or years, where you really do need the help of the full Calendar.

Answer (score 2):

```
String startTime=date_format.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 60L * 1000L));
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.now()
       .plusSeconds( 60 )
```

## java.time

The modern way is with the java.time classes.

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instantOneMinuteLater = Instant.now().plusSeconds( 60 );
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

## Joda-Time

Update: The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

In [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3.

```
// import org.joda.time.*;

DateTime minuteLater = DateTime.now().plusMinutes( 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar afterOneMinute = Calendar.getInstance();
afterOneMinute.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
Calendar afterOneDay = Calendar.getInstance();
afterOneDay.add(Calendar.DAY, 1);

SimpleDateFormat isoFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(isoFormat.format(afterOneMinute.getTime()) + " to " + isoFormat.format(afterOneDay.getTime()));
```